# group theory subgroup homework question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = S_n$ and let $H = \{\sigma \in G : \sigma(1) = 1\}$. Let $\tau \in G$ and suppose
$\tau(i) = 1$. By $\tau H\tau^{−1}$ we mean all elements of the form $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ where $\sigma\in H$.

(a) Show that if $\gamma \in \tau H \tau^{-1}$ then $\gamma(i) = i$.

(b) Show that if $\gamma(i) = i$ then $\gamma \in \tau H \tau^{−1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

If $\gamma \in \tau H \tau^{-1}$, then there exists an $h \in H$ for which $\gamma = \tau h \tau^{-1}$. Check that $\tau^{-1}(1) = 1$, and just compute $\gamma(1) = \tau(h(1))$ using the definition of $H$.

For (b), suppose that $\gamma(i) = i$. Then show that $\tau \gamma \tau^{-1} \in H$ (what is the necessary and sufficient property for inclusion in $H$?), and rearrange.